# How to delete duplicate records in a table using Orientdb

Tags: database, orientdb, nosql

```
Select * from table
cola colb
a     b
a     c
a     b
a     b
```

How to delete duplicate records excluding the first entry in a table.Expected result :

```
 Select * from table
cola colb
a     b
a     c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can try the following solution: 
1. Create new (temporary) class

```
create class table_temp
```

2. Insert grouped (distinct) values to new class table

   `insert into table_temp from select cola, colb from your_table 
   group by cola, colb`
3. Clean your table `delete from your_table`
4. Insert data from new table 
   `insert into your_table from select cola, colb from table_temp 
   group by cola, colb`

Ideally, these steps should be done within single transaction.

Comment: Ok, so you just start transaction, perform the steps above and commit transaction.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion It should be done in a single query not a transaction.

Comment: This could be done using this query:  `delete from your_table
where @rid not in(select first(list(@rid)) from your_table group by cola, colb order by @rid)`

Comment: That's the solution .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

delete from your_table where @rid not in(select first(list(@rid)) from your_table group by cola, colb order by @rid)